# Unexpected view on FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

[image]

As you can see, there is a strange view on `FloatingActionButton` compared to the `ImageView` above.

It looks like a ripple effect cause the area open wider when I tap on it.

How to remove it?

The xml layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d_20"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:tint="@null"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/d_48"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:maxImageSize="@dimen/d_48"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_go_top" />
```